# #1093 Table 'table' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

**not getting desire result in mysql query**

*i have searched a lot but didn't find solution*

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE username NOT IN (select t1.id from table1 as t1
inner join table1 as t2 on t1.username = t2.username and t1.id <= t2.id 
group by t1.username , t1.id having count(*) <= 5 order by t1.username , t1.id desc);
```

Output is as follows:-

[image: query should delete all rows except last 5 rows of each username]

Comment: Comes up a lot try googling your exact message.

Comment: It would help if you added sample data to your question, Doesn't have to be much you could reduce the sample size so that < 2 is represented

Comment: Please explain the logic that you want to implement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to keep only last N records of each user_id and delete the remaining data from the table.

Answer (score 1):

should work for you

```
delete from
    table1
where
    id in ( select
                id
            from
                (   select
                        *,
                        row_number() over(  partition by
                                                username
                                            order by
                                                id desc) as rn
                    from 
                        table1)
            where
                rn > 5)
```

Comment: Should? Only if OP is on version 8.0 or above

Comment: getting error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(  partition by username order by id desc) as rn from  table1) where rn >' at line 1

Comment: @Manish Verma this question is incorrectly tagged - you should not regard mariadb as the same product as mysql. I have changed the tags. AND what version of mariadb are you on?

Comment: @P.Salmon it's 10.1.40-MariaDB

Comment: Window functions were first introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0 so the answer is not suitable for you.(unless you want to upgrade)

Comment: whereas it's working fine like charm in mariaDB v10.4.6 !!  it seems it is bug of mariadb earlier version

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to keep the most recent five ids for each user name.  I think the simplest method uses window functions:

```
delete t1
    from table1 t1 join
         (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by username order by id desc) as seqnum
          from table1 t1
         ) tt1
         on t1.username = tt1.username and
            t1.id = tt1.id
    where tt1.seqnum > 5;
```

Comment: still getting error #1064. it seems it is cause of their limitation and some functions are not supported by mariaDB's earlier version !!